# Save html made in CKeditor Laravel

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I want to save what I do with the ckeditor as a new document and use it as a view in laravel is possible? Any idea how I could do it?

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not providing and code, but you can do something like this and it should work. because this is just a WYSIWYG editor, you will need to use `{!!$post(or whatever)->content!!}`, this way every styling you make with the editor will be saved in the database and will not be escaped.

Comment: hi eitan 
The problem is this: -> change for: -&gt; when I save the template with blade labels

Answer (score 0):

This is the controller where I keep everything in the ckeditor and saves it in the view resource

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $ruta = base_path().'/resources/views/oficios/pdf/';
  $nombre = "p.blade.php";
  $archivo= $request->editor1;
  \Storage::disk('pdf')->put($nombre, $archivo);

  dd('Plantilla Guardada');
}
```

This is the html that is created with ckeditor for example:

```
<p><strong><em><s>{{ $oficio-&gt;subject }}</s></em></strong></p>
```

Then in another view I include `@include ('oficios.pdf.p')`
 And it is there where I mark error by the character